# How to solve $3\times 10^{8} = x \times \log_{10} x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The answer is $3.96\times 10^{7}$ but I am not sure how this is done step by step. I tried using the fact $\log_b (y) = x \leftrightarrow b^{x} = y$ but can't get around it. Please advise.

Comment: This is a transcendental equation. You need [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: But you can use [Newton–Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) do approximate the solution.

Comment: only a solution in the LambertW function is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not exist an elementary solution for $x$. For analytical methods, the best we can do is obtain a solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W(z)$:

Here is the definition given by Wikipedia:

> **Definition:** In mathematics, the Lambert-W function, also called the omega function or product logarithm, is a set of functions, namely the branches of the inverse relation of the function $f(z) = ze^z$ where $e^z$ is the exponential function and $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

---

Let's start using the fact that:
$$\log_{10}{x}\equiv \frac{\ln{x}}{\ln{10}}$$
Substituting this, we obtain:
$$3\times 10^8\cdot \ln{10}=x\cdot \ln{x}$$
Now, we can substitute $x=e^u$. That way, we can use the definition of the Lambert W.

$$3\times 10^8\cdot \ln{10}=u\cdot e^u$$

Applying the definition, we obtain: 
$$u=W(3\times 10^8\cdot \ln{10})$$
Hence, we obtain our exact solution for $x$:
$$\large x=e^{W(3\times 10^8\cdot \ln{10})}$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Honestly, I am not familiar with Lambert W function so I guess I have to go through it first but I would like to briefly ask are there some specific methods to actually calculate $W(3\times10^{8} \cdot \ln10)$ by hands and calculator?

Comment: @M.A.N I do not know of a method to compute it by hand. However, you can compute the values numerically using, for example the [Newton-Raphson Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). See [Numerical evaluation of the $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation). You could use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approximate+e%5E(LambertW(3*10%5E8*ln(10)))), and it should provide a value.

Comment: @M.A.N  When faced with an equation like this with no algebraic solution you can often resort to guess-and-check with your calculator (or the Google calculator). Repeat guesses until you're close enough. Later in your mathematical studies you may learn about the Newton-Raphson method others have pointed you to, but you don't have to learn it to make some headway now with problems like this one.

Comment: @EthanBolker, thanks for your advice. It is a great one. You are right, I am currently studying some fundamental math like calculus, discrete math, probability and linear algebra. I am not sure if I would cover them, but if I did not, may I know what course would I come across Newton-Raphson and other numerical evaluation?

Comment: @M.A.N You might find Newton-Raphson as an example in a calculus course. You'd certainly learn enough in a calculus course to read about it, starting at the wikipedia page. You'd certainly study Newton Raphson in a course on numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to give a numerical answer only. If this is the case, use www.desmos.com graphing calculator to find the intersection of two curves:
$$ y = \log_{10}x, $$
$$ y = \frac{3\cdot10^8}{x}.$$

Comment: I disagreed with whoever thought my answer is not useful. My 11-th grade kid was given this kind of problem and the only way for him to solve was to use a graph calculator. For physicists and engineers, we use one of several numerical methods such as the Newton method, etc.

Comment: Hi Hoc Ngo, thank you for your suggestion. As the person who initiates this question, I feel I have the obligation to publicly give you my support. I thought your method is useful. In fact, I graphed $y = 3 \times 10^{8}$ and $y = x \cdot \log_{10} x$ (WLOS, I suppose they are the same) and I approximate the answer. Although I am still a student and maybe no qualified to evaluate critically, I feel this is generally right.

Comment: @HocNgo I think this is a useful answer. It is a different approach than mine, and could help other users who are not familiar with certain numerical methods or the Lambert W function (+1)

Comment: @M.A.N, you can graph any way you like. In fact, you can simply graph $y=x\log_{10}x - 3\cdot 10^8$ and locate the intersection with the $x$ axis. In my previous solution, I broke down into two familiar functions so one could have a feeling about what the intersection means.  FYI, transcendental equations are usually solved by numerical methods. Thanks you and  projectilemotion for your understanding that a numerical solution, either by graphing or by numerical methods, is just as good as any other solution when the problem asks for the explicit value of the solution.